# Nested (*ng-for table) table with certain specifications

Tags: angular, html-table

I am trying to achieve below table shown as in picture. I was able to get the "single row" section working but the Headers are all out of place. I have failed miserably trying to get the requirement to accomplish. Any good pointers, or help would make me sleep an hour at peace :D.[image]

Basicall, the section that says "Single Row" is being repeated by *ng-for in angular 2 where the values are coming from Rest API.

UPDATE: I have been able to get the static working. but not sure how to make it work with *ng-for to repeat the row(Single Row).

http://jsfiddle.net/gzTCL/

looking for something that like- (below one is not valid, but that's the interpretation of what am looking for)

```
<tr *ngFor="">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <tr class="extra">
     <td colspan="3">test</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal, I have tried and failed to get the result and since Stack Overflow is filled with great developers who might have already solved what problem am encountering, I am here as my last hope. I am trying to create a plunkr with what I have done so far. But, I honestly appreciate you checking out my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is invalid because `<tr>` cannot be nested into another `<tr>`

Try `ng-container` that will allow you to have 2 neighbour `tr` elements

```
<ng-container *ngFor="">
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="extra">
    <td colspan="3">test</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: you ave no idea how much this has helped. THANKYOU a TON! Upvoted!!